How can solve error downloading file from my web in VBA?
I need to perform a function to download a file from a website. I have tested with the Public Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile function and it does not work on my website http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/prueba/2400px-Hong_Kong_at_night.jpg but it does work for another website like link workling from Wikipedia
What could be the problem? I have also tried with CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") and I run this code but the result I get with WinHttpReq.Status is always a 403 error:
Private Sub DownloadFile(myURL As String, target As String)

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL2 = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    Debug.Print myURL2
    Debug.Print myURL
    Debug.Print "WinHttpReq.Status=" & WinHttpReq.Status

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
     Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     oStream.Open
     oStream.Type = 1
     oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
     oStream.SaveToFile target, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
     oStream.Close
    End If
    Set WinHttpReq = Nothing
End Sub

I test it too with user and password with the same result.
What is the problem with my website and how can I solve it to download files?
Regards
Download web file from VBA Excel
Download file in VBA from link http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/prueba/2400px-Hong_Kong_at_night.jpg from my web

The link you posted to your site doesn't work

I got a redirect to https://giftcardsgames.com/ when I click your link. There is no picture behind.

Because I was curious.
You can reach your target with "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" and you must sending the referer in the request header.
Sub getImg()

  Dim oStream As Object
  
  With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/prueba/2400px-Hong_Kong_at_night.jpg", False
    .setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/"
    .send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      oStream.Open
      oStream.Type = 1
      oStream.Write .responseBody
      oStream.SaveToFile "E:\test.jpg", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
      oStream.Close
    Else
      Debug.Print .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub

If that don't work, try the longer version with two calls and the ETag from the first responseHeader. (The reason, why I tryed "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1". To get cookies we need this technologie. Here we have no cookies, but ETag looks like a seassionID):
Sub getImgWithETag()
  Dim ETag As String
  Dim oStream As Object
  
  With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/", False
    .send
    'Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders()
    'Debug.Print .GetResponseHeader("ETag")
    ETag = .GetResponseHeader("ETag")

    .Open "GET", "http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/prueba/2400px-Hong_Kong_at_night.jpg", False
    .setRequestHeader "ETag", ETag
    .setRequestHeader "Referer", "http://pavimarcon.atwebpages.com/"
    .send
    If .Status = 200 Then
      'Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders()
      Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
       oStream.Open
       oStream.Type = 1
       oStream.Write .responseBody
       oStream.SaveToFile "E:\test.jpg", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
       oStream.Close
    Else
      Debug.Print .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub

